# How do i transmit the ETX command in powershell?

Tags: powershell, ascii, barcode-scanner

I program scanners currently at work and im driven in a corner.
I use a Zebra LI3678 to scan barcodes with the ITF-14 method.
The scanner is supposed to use the ascii STX command as a prefix and the ascii ETX command as a suffix.
Now when i scan the code, powershell shows ^B and ^C in yellow which means that powershell doesnt see it as a command.
When i use my other wired scanner, the ^C is in red and the command is actually executed. The other scanner is a Symbol LS2208 and is readable with the same software. I copied everything from this scanner to the other but i get different results.
I also have disabled keypad emulation to check if that worked but alas.
Is there anything i have missed or can do to solve this?

[image: Top is wired and properly programmed, bottom is the new scanner]

Comment: Maybe `"$([char]2)123456789012$([char]3)"`?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Rethink what you really want to do and what's wrong with it.